# Firebase: Debugging insufficient permissions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

I have a large app and expanding the error object is not helping me at all. Is there a way to read the permissions error log in Firestore so I can see what `document` or `collection` was disallowed?

Comment: There is no "permissions error log" you can read.

Comment: Logging of unauthorized access attempts is a fundamental security feature...?

Comment: You're always free to file a feature request.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Comment: @DougStevenson A optional `log` keyword on the `match` statement(s) in `firestore.rules` would be how to implement it. The log should record the operation type, e.g. `create`,`update`,etc, and the `uid` if any - along with a timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

I went from having no information about the error to:

```
Uncaught FirebaseError: 
false for 'get' @ L167, false for 'get' @ L207
```

By using the [firebase firestore emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/emulator-setup) . I highly recommend it, along with the using the emulator UI.